# Reloading only child state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, state

I have nested UI states. I want to load only child state not the parent state.

**Child State** :

```
$stateProvider.state('app.test', {
    url: '^/test?search',
    controller: 'TestController',
    templateUrl: 'test/test.tpl.html',
    pageTitle: 'Tests',
 });
```

**Parent State** :

```
 $stateProvider.state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'parent/main-content.tpl.html',
    controller: 'ParentController'
 })
```

When I try to load only child state in test page using

```
 $state.go('.', {search: searchTerm});
```

It loads only child state.

And when I try `$state.reload();`, it loads both state and so there controllers. 
If I don't have **searchTerm** parameter for state, then how can I load only current state ?

Answer (score 0):

$state.go($state.current) will do that

Answer (score 0):

use **$state.reload('childstate')** or $state.go('state',{params},**{reload: "childstate"}**)

This will do the stuff you needed.