# Refresh a state without refreshing its master view in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I refresh the 'detail' state without refreshing its parent (item).
in routes:

```
  $stateProvider.state('item.detail', {
    url: '/:id/detail',
    abstract: true,
    resolve: {
      $modal: ['$modal', function ($modal) {
        return $modal;
      }]
    },
    onEnter: ['$state', '$modal', function ($state, $modal) {
      $modal
        .open({
          templateUrl: 'detail.html',
          backdrop: 'static'
        })
        .result.then(function () {
            $state.transitionTo('item.detail', {id: $state.params.id}, {reload: true});
        })
      ;
    }]

  })
```

This refreshes the item and detail together.

Adding the state the to reload also doesn't work.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS UI Router $state reload child state only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316591/angularjs-ui-router-state-reload-child-state-only)

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316591/angularjs-ui-router-state-reload-child-state-only) what you want to do, I think the interesting part if the reload argument (that you are using):

> If reload is a string (or state object), the state object is fetched
>   (by name, or object reference); and \ the transition reloads the
>   resolves and views for that matched state, and all its children
>   states.

Comment: None of the solutions worked in my case, at least with my trying. This question is quite similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37543098/reloading-only-child-state